# Best way to store data on iOS for list with 100s of items (possibly 1000s)

Tags: sqlite, swift, core-data, plist, nsuserdefaults

I am developing an app which presents a feed of posts and allows users to vote on these posts.

I want to prevent users from voting multiple times on a single post. To do that, I want to store a list of id's of the posts voted on already so that I can check that each time the user tries to vote.

What's the most efficient way of storing these post IDs if there's a chance of the user voting on up to thousands of posts within a year?

Sqlite, core data, p list or nsuserdefaults?

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make much sense. In a typical client-server system, the server should be the ultimate source of truth. Unless the server has a way to determine whether a client has voted yet, votes are meaningless. You don't necessarily have to create a "user profile", per se, but you absolutely need a way to uniquely identify clients from one another.

Answer (score 0):

Since you would also like to know how many people voted (I think), I would save it to a server (using sqlite to store it).
Saving this on a user device seems redundant.
If you do want to store it I would advice Core Data.
It is too much information for NSUserdata, plists… I don’t know why but it just doesn’t seem like a good idea, and Coredata is just a better version of Sqlite (for swift usage)

Comment: This app doesn't use any user accounts. So unless I generate a unique identifier each time an app is installed, I won't be able to keep record of people's votes.

Comment: Why can people vote? If you want to do something with the votes you will have to store how many people voted so you will have to save them somewhere. (I’m making assumptions here due too a lack of information). All of the options you suggest will be cleared when a users uninstalls an app. Is it okay that a user can vote a unlimited amount of times on the same post if he reinstalls the app every time? If it is go ahead and store it locally otherwise you do need to store the info on a server.

Comment: The votes will be stored on a server but users won't need an account to use this app. I'm ok with them being able to vote multiple times if they reinstall over and over (because it's unlikely anyone will want to do this I think)

Comment: And I still do not see a edit to you question to include this really (REALLY) important data

Comment: So if the votes are stored on the server, why don't you just request the list of posts with userId (generated when app first starts)...server can send only boolean if user with this id already voted or not.